# Google log in only works in dev build

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I've been working on an application that features google log in to a back end server. After all the pain this has been giving me, is finally working, but only in the debug flavor of the app.
I have a pretty standard configuration on my gradle, with 2 build types(debug and release) and 2 flavors as well(debug and release) with their respective signatures.
Whichever combination featuring the debug keystore works, it logs in successfully and everything is fine, however, if I use the release keystore, it never works.
I created a OAuth web credential for this on the credentials console and when I saw that was working on debug, I thought that was it but it wasn't. Any clues for this odd behavior?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added your release version SHA-1 fingerprint?

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan thing is, I'm using the web client id, and when this is created, it doesn't ask for fingerprints nor package name

Answer (score 0):

You missed this part of the instruction from the same guide you're following:

> [Configure a Google API Console
> project](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#configure_a_console_name_project)
>
> To configure a Google API Console project, click the button below, and
> specify your app's package name when prompted. You will also need to
> provide the SHA-1 hash of your signing certificate. See
> [Authenticating Your
> Client](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) for
> information.

which then will lead you to..

You need to [Sign Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html) which involves using a release key (not for debug version anymore) and after that be [Prepared for Release](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html).

Comment: I followed this and it seems to be working, but there's no client secret available and I need it to validate the token I just got, any ideas?